# Filter by two timestamp fields in Cassandra

Tags: sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a table in cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE measurements
(
    device_id            text,
    first_measurement_time   timestamp,
    last_measurement_time    timestamp

PRIMARY KEY ...
)
```

How should I configure primary key if my queries will be like:

```
select * from measurements 
where device_id=? 
    and first_measurement > ? 
    and last_measurement < ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have inequality condition on two different columns, even if they are both part of the primary key.  Cassandra requires that if you're doing inequality comparison on the clustering column, all previous clustering columns must have equality condition.

if you're doing search only inside partition (`device_id`), then you can enforce execution of this query using `ALLOW FILTERING`, although it's generally not recommended, and could lead to the higher read latencies.  In this case, you can put both columns into the primary key as clustering columns.  And then do the performance testing, for example, using [NoSQLBench](https://github.com/nosqlbench).

Comment: thanks for your answer. then I plan to filter only by first field but with some possible range like:
first_measurement > (X-(x days)) and first_measurement < X